# Como armazenar informações ao sair de um aplicativo e recuperar no próximo uso?

Tags: android

Eu gostaria de saber como armazenar informações, como por exemplo esta variável:

```
int t = 0;
```

Vamos dizer que durante o uso do aplicativo, o usuario fez alguma operação que adicionou + 5 nesta variável.

Como faço para quando o usuário fechar o aplicativo, o valor continuar a ser 5 no próximo uso, em vez de voltar a 0?

Eu quero armazenar em um banco de dados os floats gf e mf.

Meu codigo :

```
package com.gustavo.sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button send;
    TextView say;
    EditText num;
    CheckBox g;
    CheckBox m;
    float gf = 0;
    float mf = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bacon();

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String counter = num.getText().toString();
                if (counter.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Digite um valor numerico", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                } else {
                    float counterAsFloat = Float.parseFloat(counter);
                    if (g.isChecked() && m.isChecked()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Selecione apenas um checkbox",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else if (m.isChecked()) {
                        mf = mf + counterAsFloat;
                        say.setText("Math " + Float.toString(mf));
                    } else if (g.isChecked()) {
                        gf = gf + counterAsFloat;
                        say.setText("Geo " + Float.toString(gf));
                    } else
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Selecione um checkbox", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private void bacon() {
        g = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        m = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        say = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    }

}
```

Comment: Dei uma leve editada na sua pergunta para ficar mais fácil de ser localizada por outros usuários. Confira se é isto mesmo que quer saber. Se preferir, pode [edit] a pergunta e deixar melhor, ou mesmo reverter minha edição, caso não tenha ficado boa.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, eu sou iniciante no forum e ainda não tenho muita expreiencia ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recomendo você usar **SharedPreferences** por ser simples para o seu caso(gravação de um inteiro), que:

> > - Armazena as preferências em arquivos;
> > - Por padrão, são compartilhadas entre os componentes da sua aplicação, mas não são visíveis para outras aplicações;
> > - As preferências são salvar na forma de pares de chave e valor.

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private int t = 0;
        private SharedPreferences save;
        private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            save = getSharedPreferences("save",
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            t = save.getInt("valor", 0);//recupera o valor armazenado na chave "valor" e default 0
        }
        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            editor = save.edit();
            editor.putInt("valor", t);//seta o par de chave("valor") e valor(t)
            editor.commit();//grava a preferencia
        }

    }
```

**No caso do seu código você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button send;
    TextView say;
    EditText num;
    CheckBox g;
    CheckBox m;
    float gf = 0;
    float mf = 0;
    private SharedPreferences save;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bacon();
        save = getSharedPreferences("save",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        gf = save.getFloat("valorGeo", 0);//recupera o valor armazenado na chave "valorGeo" e default 0
        mf = save.getFloat("valorMath", 0);//recupera o valor armazenado na chave "valorMath" e default 0
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String counter = num.getText().toString();
                if (counter.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Digite um valor numerico", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                } else {
                    float counterAsFloat = Float.parseFloat(counter);
                    if (g.isChecked() && m.isChecked()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Selecione apenas um checkbox",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else if (m.isChecked()) {
                        mf = mf + counterAsFloat;
                        say.setText("Math " + Float.toString(mf));
                    } else if (g.isChecked()) {
                        gf = gf + counterAsFloat;
                        say.setText("Geo " + Float.toString(gf));
                    } else
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Selecione um checkbox", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        editor = save.edit();
        editor.putFloat("valorGeo", gf);//seta o par de chave("valorGeo") e valor(gf)
        editor.putFloat("valorMath", mf);//seta o par de chave("valorMath") e valor(mf)
        editor.commit();//grava a preferencia
    }

    private void bacon() {
        g = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        m = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        say = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    }

}
```

Comment: Meu amigo, seu codigo não está pegando está dando unfortunately ...

Comment: @Gutie pode ser algum erro no seu layout... pois pra mim e pra muitas pessoas não apresenta nenhum erro.

Comment: @Gutie vou editar minha resposta só um momento...

Comment: @Gutie editei olha novamente na parte "No caso do seu código você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:"

Comment: Nossa valeu denovo mano kkk

Answer (score 7):

Há várias maneiras de se armazenar dados de aplicativos no Android.

Eis as mais comuns:

- **Armazenamento interno:** para armazenar dados privativos no dispositivo;
- **Preferências compartilhadas:** guarda dados em chaves => valores;
- **Banco de dados:** para armazenar uma quantidade maior e mais "processável" de informação;
- **Web:** caso você queira os dados armazenados num servidor seu, e não do usuário

### Armazenamento interno:

É basicamente uma gravação em arquivo:

```
String ARQUIVO = "NomeDoMeuArquivo";
String string = "Batatinhas";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput( ARQUIVO, Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

### Preferências compartilhadas:

Veja um exemplo:

```
public class Teste extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "PreferenciasNOME_DO_APP";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
       super.onCreate(state);
       . . .

       // Recuperando os dados no início da aplicação
       SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
       boolean minhaVariavel = settings.getBoolean("minhaVariavel", false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
       super.onStop();

      // Gravando dados na saída
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putBoolean("minhaVariavel", minhaVariavel );
      editor.commit();
    }
}
```

**[Clique aqui](http://www.klebermota.eti.br/2012/08/16/opcoes-de-armazenamento-no-android-traducao-da-documentacao-oficial/)** para visitar um artigo com uma tradução interessante da documentação oficial do Android.

Comment: Sim, sua resposta está perfeita porém o meu está dando um erro ainda quando o usuario coloca a informação e fecha o app, e depois abre novamente não está aparecendo o valor lá continua novamente em 0 em vez de ficar 5.

Comment: E na realidade eu não quero uma string quero uma int.

Comment: aí teria que ver seu código mesmo, cuidado pra nao sobreescrever a variavel depois de recuperar. O tipo vc pode mudar à vontade, foi só um exemplo. No segundo exemplo, o o putBoolean poderia ser putFloat, por exemplo, putInt

Comment: Postei meu codigo la em baixo

Comment: Ué, mas no seu código não tem nada do que eu coloquei na resposta. Bom, preciso sair pra um compromisso, mais a noite dou uma espiada melhor. Procure atualizar seu código com os dados da resposta e fazer uns testes.

Comment: Beleza valeu vou testar aqui