# Como é possível fazer uma Activity aparecer apenas uma vez para o usuário?

Tags: android, eclipse

Meu plano é o seguinte: No meu projeto eu tenho 2 Activitys; Essas duas activitys são apenas de boas vindas para o usuário, então eu precisaria que ela aparecesse apenas na primeira vez que o usuário iniciasse o aplicativo.

Eu comecei a estudar Shared Preferences, mas os materiais que eu acho por aí são apenas sobre como fazer Login/Senha para o usuário. Não encontrei nenhuma demonstração de como realizar o meu problema. Eu posso usar o Shared Preferences? De qual forma?

Comment: Não sei se é duplicata, mas tem três perguntas relacionadas a `SharedPreferences` que já estão respondidas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33677/como-salvar-lista-de-objetos-em-android/33698#33698, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25167/salvar-string-sharedpreference e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/como-armazenar-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-ao-sair-de-um-aplicativo-e-recuperar-no-pr%C3%B3ximo-uso/34572#34572. Sua dúvida é como fazer essa lógica no início do app ou como usar `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: Na verdade é de como utilizar o SharedPreferences no início da minha aplicação. Eu não tenho exatamente a "lógica" de como usar pro meu objetivo. Todos os materiais que achei só ensinam a como usar o SharedPreferences pra sistemas de login, mas nenhum como usar em uma Activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é diferente de sistemas de login como você encontrou ou como sugerido. Supondo que você tenha um **BoasVindasActivity** e um **MainActivity** (este último definido como principal no seu arquivo *manifest*), tem algo assim no *MainActivity*:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(NOME_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

if (!sharedPrefs.getBoolean("primeiroAcesso", false)) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BoasVindasActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

    return;
}
```

Ou seja, se entrou no *main* e não tem o `primeiroAcesso` salvo nas preferências do usuário, vai para a tela de boas-vindas. Caso contrário, no seu *BoasVindasActivity* você salva essa opção em algum momento para abrir a principal:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("primeiroAcesso", true);
editor.commit();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

A mesma verificação no início você também pode fazer na *BoasVindasActivity*, para evitar abrir esta tela caso já esteja salvo.