# sharedpreferences na primeira Activity, mostrar somente uma vez?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Estou desenvolvendo uma app em que nela terá a primeira `Activity` de saudação, e quero mostra-la apenas uma vez, apenas quando o app for aberto pela primeira vez.

Neste caso, eu criei uma `Activity` chamando um layout onde contém o *textview* e *button*, assim que o usuário clicar no botão, vai abrir a `Activity` principal da app, e em seguida, não quero a `Activity` de saudação seja mostrada mais.

Meu layout (resumido):

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Saudação Aqui" />

<Button 
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:onClick="sendMessage"
android:text="Ok, entrar para Activity principal e não mostrar mais essa tela" />
```

Activity de saudação:

```
Button button;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); 

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Activity Principal.class);
    startActivity(i); 
} 
}); 
}
```

Muito obrigado!

Comment: Não entendi a sua dúvida!! Você já implementou algo para salvar no **SharedPreferences** ?

Comment: Você pode encontrar algo semelhante aqui [nesta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/41333/4337).

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski É que sou iniciante amigo, estou bem no comecinho do mundo da programação. O que eu queria manipular, era esta Activity (de saudação) para mostrar apenas uma vez. Não sei exatamente como "montar" (implementar) com sharedpreferences. Neste caso, você poderia me dá um exemplo de como fazer essa manipulação?

Comment: @PauloRodrigues Ok amigo, muito obrigado. Irei dá uma olhadinha ;)

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro você implementa uma classe para gerenciar o SharedPreferences (por organização).

```
public class PreferencesManager {
    public static final String ENTERING_FIRST_TIME = "EnteringFirstTime";

    public static void storeInt(Context context, String key, int value) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static int getInt(Context context, String key, int defaultValue){
        return context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(key, defaultValue);
    }
}
```

Então, quando seu app iniciar, você pode verificar dessa forma:

```
if(PreferencesManager.getInt(view, PreferencesManager.ENTERING_FIRST_TIME, 1) == 1){
    //Salva informação de que o usuário já entrou no app a primeira vez
    PreferencesManager.storeInt(view, PreferencesManager.ENTERING_FIRST_TIME, 0);
    //Exibe saudação
}
else{
    //Esconde saudação
}
```

O ideal é fazer a leitura e a gravação de informações no SharedPreferences fora da UI thread, para evitar que sua aplicação seja destruída por ANR (Application Not Responding). ANR's acontecem quando sua aplicação processa alguma coisa por mais tempo do que o permitido na Thread principal (cinco segundos).

Pode parecer impossível que uma tarefa tão simples leve mais de cinco segundos, porém, em alguns casos de concorrência por recursos pode acontecer.

Você pode prevenir isso chamando o segundo bloco de código dentro de uma 
[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: Muito bom amigo, muito obrigado pela resposta. Estava pensando, neste caso daria também para colocar um simples diálogo (ex: igual aqueles termos do app com botão: Li, aceito, Não aceito) para ser mostrado apenas uma vez, o que você acha? Seria mais simples, certo? E creio evitaria que a minha aplicação seja destruída por ANR.

Comment: e  qual o critério pra exibir ou não o dialog? Não adianta fugir da AsyncTask, ela vai te perseguir rs  mas é moleza

Comment: É que neste caso amigo, eu colocaria o diálogo de boas vindas dentro da própria Activity Principal e apenas chamaria o sharedpreferences para ele aparecer apenas uma vez. Essa lógica está certa?

Comment: Funcionar vai, só não é boa prática fazer isso síncrono... tem uma bem pequena chance de dar erro